# Stop jboss 5.x from shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell, jboss, jboss5.x

I am writing some small shell script utility which automates deployment process. I ready many links related to command for shutting down the jboss server in linux so that I can shutdown the server from my utility.

Read some links which will tell how to do it in jboss 7 or later but not in old jboss versions like 5.x.  One such is

```
 "$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh" --connect command=:shutdown
```

I want to shutdown the jboss 5.2 version from my shell script?

Edit: Jboss 5 version has shutdown.sh in the bin folder. But I am getting the below exception when I say

```
sh shutdown.sh -S


[john@mymachine bin]$ sh shutdown.sh  -S
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1851)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:720)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:713)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.jboss.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:225)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:362)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:287)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1821)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:332)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Any idea ??

Regards

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 5 has a `shutdown.sh`, from the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/start-stop.html):

```
usage: shutdown [options] <operation>

options:
  -h, --help              Show this help message (default)
  -D<name>[=<value>]      Set a system property
  --                      Stop processing options
  -s, --server=<url>      Specify the JNDI URL of the remote server
  -n, --serverName=<url>  Specify the JMX name of the ServerImpl
  -a, --adapter=<name>    Specify JNDI name of the MBeanServerConnection to use
  -u, --user=<name>       Specify the username for authentication
  -p, --password=<name>   Specify the password for authentication

operations:
  -S, --shutdown          Shutdown the server
  -e, --exit=<code>       Force the VM to exit with a status code
  -H, --halt=<code>       Force the VM to halt with a status code
```

Comment: Hey Paizo. Thanks for the reply. But shutdown.sh is not working. See my updated question.

Comment: Is there a command so we can wait until JBoss 5 finishes the stopping process?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should check your JBoss configuration and look for the JNP port. Probably you are running with a non default port and that's why you receive the connection refused exception.
Have a look at the file `server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml`.

Reference https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigurePorts

Answer (score 0):

If you have on ubuntu with default visual interface, open the "System Monitor", change to tab Process and filter by "jboss", it's will result in a java process, kill then.